# Upload an image (if it exists) before updating a user profile using observables

Tags: angular, observable

I'm new to using observables and I'm quite lost at the moment. I'm working on a Angular component that updates a user profile. The user can either select a profile picture (which needs to be uploaded first to get an ID) or remove the image by setting it to null. After the image is handled, profile data is updated. Below is a simplified code of what I currently have. I'm confident that there must be a much more elegant way of doing this. Are that many subscriptions required, is it possible to just have one at the end? The most bothering thing to me is the subscribe within subscribe (after map), but I was not able to figure out how to get rid of it.

```
save() {
    if (this.newImage !== undefined) {

        // User wants to remove profile picture
        if (this.newImage === null) {
            this.form.get('profileImageId').setValue(null);
            this.userService.update(this.form.value).subscribe(...);
        }

        // User wants to upload a new profile picture
        else if (this.newImage instanceof File) {
            this.fileService.upload(this.newImage)
            .map((res: FileUploadResult) => {
                    this.form.get('profileImageId').setValue(res.id);
                    return this.userService.update(this.form.value);
                }
            )
            .subscribe((obs: Observable<User> => {
                obs.subscribe(...);
            });
        }
    } else {
        // newImage is undefined, do not worry about image and just save user data
        this.userService.update(this.form.value).subscribe(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this might work:

```
save(){
    let $image = Observable.of("empty");

    if(image !== null){
        $image = this.fileService.upload(this.newImage)
    }

    $image.switchMap(() => {
        return this.userService.update(this.form.value)
    }).subscribe(...)
}
```